# Non-Zero exit of Perl script

Tags: perl, unix

In my Perl script, if I use `exit(-1)`, the script exits. But if I use `exit(-433)` or `exit(-233)`, it doesn't exit. Why? An example follows.

```
if ($result1[0] eq "Error") {
    print "Error occurred while updating https route\n";
    print "Error returned from the script:\n";
    print $result1[1];
    exit(-377);
}
```

Comment: On Unix, exit values are supposed to be an unsigned integer 0-255.  Still, I can't see why that would fail.  Does this happen with a script that contains nothing but the `exit` statement?

Comment: You mean `exit 233` does nothing at all? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: sorry its -233 only exit -1 exits the script but if any other error i am exiting with different exit code but it doesn't exit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `perlbug` to submit a bug report. Despite your incorrect argument, that shouldn't prevent `exit` from functioning.

As you can see (by the face that `y` is never printed), I can't replicate this on a Linux system:

```
$ perl -E'say "x"; exit($ARGV[0]); say "y";' -- -377 ; echo $?
x
135

$ perl -E'say "x"; exit($ARGV[0]); say "y";' -- -1 ; echo $?
x
255

$ perl -E'say "x"; exit($ARGV[0]); say "y";' -- -433 ; echo $?
x
79

$ perl -E'say "x"; exit($ARGV[0]); say "y";' -- -233 ; echo $?
x
23
```

0..255 are acceptable on unix systems. 0..65535 on Windows.

Comment: Can you duplicate this behavior?  (I don't have a UNIX environment. All of those exit codes work fine on Windows).

Comment: Is this a bug can i do something like this  exit (-455) exit(-500)

Comment: Sorry, I said is "should prevent `exit` from functioning" when I meant "shouldn't".

Comment: Is it because I am using bigger values like  exit(-456) ?

Comment: @constantlearner, those values are not valid for exit.  Only 0-255 are valid in a Unix environment.  However, *even if you use an invalid value*, `exit` should still work and your program should exit.  That is why this behavior would be a bug.

Comment: It shouldn't do what it's doing. I don't know how I can answer why. Please do as I requested and use `perlbug` to send a bug report to the Perl folks. It'll automatically include details such as your version of Perl and type of system to help them duplicate and fix the bug in `perl`.

Comment: In the meantime, the workaround is to stop passing illegal values to `exit`. Pass values in 0..255 only. Don't pass negative numbers!

Answer (score 0):

I would even restrict the exit value to 0..127, for the following reason: If your program (on Unix) is killed by signal N, the exit value is set to N+128. Hence, if you use higher exit values, you can't distinguish a "normal" exit from one forced by a signal.